# Django - How to create an admin / dashboard site (like adminLTE)

Tags: django, adminlte

I need to create an admin site where admin/staff users can control users, can check orders, see dashboard with graphs, etc.

I want to keep default admin site separate, since it's too powerful and a bit confusing for non-IT users.

[django-adminlte2](https://django-adminlte2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) can be a good solution as it provides ready-to-use [adminLTE](https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/index2.html) templates using Bootstrap v3.

I wanted to know if there are other valid alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

maybe is http://django-baton.readthedocs.io worth to take a look at